# How can I loop this script with a CSV file of URLS?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to use the following script, but instead of typing in the URL, I want it to loop and pull the URLs from `Links.CSV` file. Eventually I want to export all the results into a new CSV file.

```
import csv
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

url = (LINK)
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
Title = soup.find(id="productTitle")
Price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")

print Title.text, Price.text
```

Any help would be appreciated.